# What's wrong with this xpath expression?

Tags: javascript, xpath

http://jsbin.com/eyeqer/2/edit

```
var x = document.evaluate('//p/following-sibling::text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var theTitle = x.iterateNext();
while (theTitle){
alert(theTitle.textContent);
theTitle = x.iterateNext();
}
```

and

```
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
  <p>HW</p>

</body>
```

i expected to see "World" and "HW", but it didn't work! Why? How do i fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select nodes so you should use `*`, not `text()`.

```
var x = document.evaluate('//p/following-sibling::*', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: why pre?? i dont have such a tag!

Comment: thanks! it works!! but i have a question, though.. Why does third alert output the source code??

Comment: Because you are selecting next element, right? And if you open developer tools and check the source code of the page (jsbin source frame) you will see that script is appended after you `p` tags. So if there were `<div>Hello</div>` after your three `p` tags you would see `Hello` as 3rd alert. So if you need to select only `p` elements as `following-sibling` change XPath to `//p/following-sibling::p`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! My last question: how do i select only first sibling?? its textContent is "World". I tried '//p/following-sibling::[1]' and '//p/following-sibling[1]' but they didnt help! :(

Comment: To select only the first sibling is a little tricky: `//p[1]/following-sibling::p[position()=1]` or `//p[1]/following-sibling::*[1]`